# Как узнать, что кто-то вступил в нашу группу вконтакте?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Есть некая группа в вконтакте. Есть потенциальные клиенты, которых мы хотим благодарить (Х денег на счет) за вступление в нашу группу в вконтакте.

Нужно организовать следующий алгоритм:

1. Посетитель видит объявление о том, что мы дарим деньги на счет, если он вступит в нашу группу вконтакте;
2. Посетитель переходит в нашу группу, вступает в неё, возвращается к нам на сайт;
3. Мы каким-то образом узнаем, что посетитель в нашей группе (подписан на неё) и дарим ему денюжку на счет.

Как узнать, что пользователь вступил в нашу группу вконтакте?

Comment: Пользователь отписывается, снова заходит в группу, подписывается, переходит на ваш сайт и фармит деньги.

Comment: Нет, естественно у пользователя будет аккаунт у нас на сайте и получить подарок можно будет только один раз. К тому же эти деньги он сможет потратить на билет участия в мероприятиях - потому заработать тут что-либо и вывести не получится.

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм примерно следующий:

- Пользователь нажимает кнопку **Вступить в группу**
- Открывается новое окно, где располагаются три кнопки:

  - авторизоваться
  - перейти на сайт (то есть в ВК)
  - получить бонус
- Нажав на авторизацию - происходит авторизация пользователя через, например, `Open API` контакта. Появляется окно, где он подтверждает это действие. 
  В результате авторизации вы получаете его `id` во вконтакте
- При нажатии на `Перейти на сайт` - соответственно попадает на страницу группы в ВК
- При клике на кнопку `Получить бонус` вы обращаетесь к методу контакта (через тот же `Open API`) [groups.isMember](https://vk.com/dev/groups.isMember) и проверяете этого юзера на наличие в данной группе....
- Если получили ответ от АПИ `{"response":1}` - значит всё ок.... если `{"response":0}` говорим юзеру - чтоб он сделал что от него просят))

Документация по авторизации и методам АПИ можно найти [Здесь](https://vk.com/dev)

В частности [авторизация](https://vk.com/dev/authentication) ...или [работа через Open API](https://vk.com/dev/openapi)

Список методов - https://vk.com/dev/methods, в частности [groups.isMember](https://vk.com/dev/groups.isMember)